# Change BackGround Color on List Item, when clicked until it is clicked again

Tags: typescript

I have an angular app, where I have a listbox, which is like that in HTML:

```
<a *ngFor="let satz of selSaetze" (click)=selSatzDetail(satz.timestamp) class="list-group-item" tabindex="0" role="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">{{satz.id}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12">
            <h4>{{satz.timestamp}}</h4>
            <p>{{satz.dsn}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

My goal is, that every time the user click on an item, the background color is changed and it should stay changed, until the user user click again on the same item!

How can I do that with typescript?

Comment: What has this to do with typescript? You probably want to use `:focus` in your .css

Comment: Hmm.. I have a list - the user click on several list items. The background color changes. The user click on one or two items again, the color changes again.

it's more like a "selection". I think typescript is needed.

Comment: How do you have this list? Is it from bootstrap? Or do you create it?

Answer (score 0):

I built this solution

```
 <a class="list-group-item" tabindex="0" role="row" (click)="selSatzDetail(satz.timestamp);whenClicked[i]=!whenClicked[i]"
                [style.background-color] = "whenClicked[i]  ? '#ddf1c1' : 'white'"
                *ngFor="let satz of selSaetze; let i = index">
```

whenClicked = [false, false]; in Typescript is needed.